# Design an optimized SVG for a map with many paths

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, gis

I have an SVG created from a shapefile that has let's say ~100 cities. I also have pre-computed shortest travel paths between these cities. When you click on any two cities, I want to display the shortest path between them. The problem is that I have at least 10,000-30,000 paths depending on how many cities I have (# of cities choose 2). Further, the paths are segmented into different types (for example, road vs highway), so there are even more than the # of cities choose 2 paths.

The SVG can be anywhere from a few to 100 MBs depending on the level of detail and optimizations I do to the SVG. So I am not asking about how to optimize the SVG, I am interested in whether I could rethink my current approach. Right now I just put all the paths in the SVG and set them to be hidden and change the properties when two cities are selected. I'm wondering if I can't store the paths in some other file and interactively inject them into the SVG with a script, so they're only loaded on demand. The end game is to have a nice interactive map for presenting ideas on one machine, so it's not completely necessary that I, say, optimize for server-side reasons.

Does anyone have any ideas or readings they can point me to? I'm fairly new to thinking about these kinds of problems and am open to the received wisdom which must exist.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting every possible path in the SVG, I would split them up into single node-to-node connections and store which path uses which connections in the selection logic. That way you will reduce the number of SVG elements by a huge amount, be able to store the shortest-path data in a better compressible format.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I have them as node-to-node connections, though there may be 3 paths in this connection (I have different properties for these). E.g., city A -> road -> highway -> road -> city B. There are still (# of cities choose 2) node-to-node connections. I don't know that I can reduce to a smaller number of paths than this unless I misunderstand you.

Comment: You said you had 100 choose 2 `<path>` (one for every possible city-to-city-connection) elements in your SVG, did I get that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did something with my students that may answer your question, about adding dynamically more svg paths. It can be done within an HTML document, plus a few lines of Javascript.

1. main svg is included directly into the html, but with only the minimal features:

   ```
   <body>
     <svg>
       <g id="fullg">
       <rect ...>
       <!-- additional data will be inserted here later -->
       </g>
     </svg>
   ```
2. more data, such as several

   ```
   <path id="name1" d="path_data1">
   ...
   ```

   are stored in a json file like this:

   ```
   { "items": [
      {"id":"name1", "d":"path_data1..."},
      {"id":"name2, "d":"..."},
      ... ] }
   ```
3. then with a few lines of javascript: get json data via ajax, parse, and build as many

   ```
   <g><path ...></g>
   ```

   lines as necessary.
4. add your lines into the svg: (**updated: use svg namespace**)

   ```
   var g = document.querySelector("#fullg"),
       ng = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'g'),
       np = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');
   ng.setAttribute("id","the_name_for_that_g");
   np.setAttribute("id","the_name_for_that_path");
   np.setAttribute("d","the_d_data_for_that_path");
   ng.appendChild(np);
   g.appendChild(ng);
   ```